# Spotipy's requests keep running forever

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

until 2 days ago everything was working fine but lately spotipy is not working for me anymore. Even if I try something simple like this

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials

spotify = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id="******", client_secret="******"))

print(spotify.artist("5K4W6rqBFWDnAN6FQUkS6x")['popularity'])
```

it does not output any result and keeps running "forever". What can cause the problem ? Until now I tried changing the client ids and also using the authorization code flow explained here : https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.19.0/

As I have already said it was working correctly before, I have no idea what happened

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to partially solve the problem : get a new token from the spotify for developers website and substitute it in the .cache file. The problem will be solved but the process might need to be done again.